# How do continue downloading file when user press home button in Android using Volley library

Tags: android, background, android-volley

I am trying to download video from server using Volley library in Android. I am able to download the file if application is in foreground during downloading using Volley library.

I want to continue downloading using volley library when user press home button or switch to another application.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your downloading in an IntentService.

A link to the official documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html